# I would like to use a variable to refer to a control object

Tags: excel, vba

It seems simple enough, but I can't get a handle on it. Thank you in advance for your help.

I would like to call a function passing the name and value of a textbox to a variable, then use that or another variable to refer to the values of that text box. I don't know how to use a variable to refer to the name of the object and use it as that object.

I'm trying to automate a routine that uses the value of MANY text boxes in a user form so that I don't have repeat the code 400 times with 800 
different variables.

I've tried every wording I could think of to search for other similar questions, and they were either too complicated for me to understand, or I wasn't even sure if it applied to what I was wanting.

```
    'IsolationQty & IsolationCheckBox are what I want to replace with variables
    'Determine emptyRow & Fill sheet
    If IsolationCheckBox.Value = True Then
        For i = 1 To IsolationQty
        emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

        'Transfer information
        Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = SysID.Value
        Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = InspectID.Value
        Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = LocID.Value
        Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = LayoutID.Value
        Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = "=VLOOKUP(" & Chr(34) & IsolationCheckBox.ControlTipText & Chr(34) & ", Device_Types, 2, FALSE)"
        Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = IsolationCheckBox.ControlTipText

        Next i
    End If
```

Comment: Don't think you can use a variable but you could create a function that returns a reference to your object

Comment: On a userform, `Me.Controls("controlNameHere")` will give you a reference to a specific control

Answer (score 0):

I always achieved this in a slightly different way than a with a variable. I would like to propose  different type of solution then.

This is quite simple. First loops through Controls collection of a userform. Read each Control name and address its property as I show in below code.

I hope it helps.

```
Sub LoopThroughControls()

Dim Controls As Controls
Dim control As control
Dim ControlName As String

Set Controls = UserForm1.Controls

For Each control In Controls
'Make Sure not to get or set property of a control which does not exist
'First use VBA.TypeName to check control type and address object properties accordingly
    If VBA.TypeName(control) = "Label" Then Debug.Print (UserForm1.Controls.Item(control.Name).Caption)
    If VBA.TypeName(control) = "TextBox" Then Debug.Print (UserForm1.Controls.Item(control.Name).Value)
    Debug.Print (UserForm1.Controls.Item(control.Name).Name)
Next control

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. This is great, I have learned something new from it, so thank you. Unfortunately, I probably didn't explain what I was looking for very well.

What I am looking for is a way, in the snippet I posted above, to replace the control name "IsolationQty" with the next control name. I will then have it loop to the next control e.g. "FanQty" that has a checkbox checked and run the "Transfer Information" section while also changing "IsolationCheckBox.ControlTipText" to "FanCheckBox.ControlTipText", etc.  

Thanks again!